# python script: Generate label.json file via image name as a key and string

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have generated synthetic images for training a network but unfortunately `label.json` file is missing and i want to create it by own. I think it is simple to create a `label.json` file.

**Synthetic images:**

[image]

The name of image file is same as image text and i just want to create a dictionary like below, here, image name will become key and and ignoring `_329.jpg` it becomes a string of that key.

**dic key:**"Apple_123.jpg"

**dic string:** "Apple",

**How i can achieve it?**

**My Code**

```
import json
import os
import re
import glob


path = "/media/cvpr/CM_1/COREMAX/dataset_KR/dataset/train/"
save_path = ""

lab_key = []
lab_string = []

lab_dic = {}

for img in glob.glob(path + '*.*'):
    key = os.path.basename(img)
    lab_key = os.path.basename(img)
    lab_string = key.split('_')[0]
    lab_dic = [lab_key, lab_string]
    print(lab_dic)
```

**Final Output**

```
# labels.json 

        { 
            "img_2.jpg": "am", 
            "img_3.jpg": "a", 
            "img_4.jpg": "Jedi", 
            "img_5.jpg": "!", 

        }
```

Comment: Show us what you've implemented so far. Consider starting with `import json, os, re; from pathlib import Path` so you can iterate over `folder.glob('*.jpg')`. Or perhaps you prefer to call `os.walk()`.

Comment: I will show to you ASAP i am generating dataset again because there are some problem in current dataset.